# How can I (reliably) delete only future events in Calendar?

Tags: calendar, ical

In Apple's Calendar app, it is not always possible to delete future events as a group.  It seems to consistently be possible when I create a repeating event on my own calendar, but apparently not possible when I have accepted a meeting invitation.

Here's the response when I try to delete an event I created:

[image: delete only this, or only future events]

But here's a failure on Apple's part to give me that ability:

[image]

Both give me the option to only delete the individual event, but only one gives me the option to delete future (and *not past*) events.

Is there any way around this?  Is there anyway I can delete only future meetings, without spending hours and hours doing them individually?

Comment: Would like to know too...

Comment: sometimes the deficiencies in Apple's Calendar astound me.  It was the first truly _beautiful_ calendar app, but in some ways it just sucks so badly

Answer (score 0):

There is the "end repeat" field where you can specify when/if you want the recurring event to stop.

To find it, double-click on the event, click into the section that has the date/time/repeat days/alerts/etc., and click the drop-down menu next to end repeat. If you create the recurring event without an end date it will be set to "Never," but you can change it to "After" to make the particular instance you opened the last occurrence.
[image]

I will also say that it does appear the "Delete all future events" option is unavailable when there are other people invited to the event. Like you said, you were invited to the event, so there was at least you and the person who created the event included, and so the future events delete option did not appear.

Comment: Is this available to recipients of meeting invitations, or only the creator of the event?

Comment: Looks like it's only available to the event creator. I can edit or delete the answer since it doesn't help for the original question.